# mysql connector isn't integrate in visual studio

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010

i've installed mysql connector on my pc. But when i start Visual Web Developer 2010, i if i try to add a database server, i can't find and choose Mysql server. 
I 've only Sql server, oracle and odbc driver. 
I've tried to reinstall mysql connector (msi file downloaded via Mysql web site), but it not solve.

Does Anyone have the same problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found my problem: i was using visual studio express. Express seems not integrate mysql connector !
Thank you anyway for your answer!

Comment: are you still using express edition? you solve this problem? thx :)

Answer (score 1):

I've had this problem with a previous version of the mysql connector. The installer simply skipped to integrate with Visual Studio 2010. A newer release fixes this problem:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Answer (score 0):

According to MySQL they are not allowed by Microsoft to integrate with Express-editions of visual studio.

Source:
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,579296,579401